# Getting an UltraWebGrid selected row datakey when clicking on a cell

Tags: infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I have an Infragistics UltraWebGrid bound to a datasource; I am trying to allow the user to change the value of a few cells in the row, so I am trapping the CellClick event in code behind. While the event's argument gives me the cell key (which is the column name), I still need to have the selected row DataKey so as to make the change in the database. Anyone knows how to get that?
Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the igtbl_getCellById utility function to get the cell.  Once you have the cell, you can get it's row and then it's key:

```
var cell = igtbl_getCellById(cellId);
var row = cell.getRow();
var key = row.DataKey
```

The following references may be helpful:

- [WebGrid utility functions](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/current/CLR4.0/?page=WebGrid_Utility_Functions_CSOM.html)
- [API documentation for the Cell object](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/current/CLR4.0/?page=WebGrid_cell_Object_CSOM.html)
- [API documentation for the Row object](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/current/CLR4.0/?page=WebGrid_row_Object_CSOM.html)

Alan